# php going in previous page and write something

Tags: php, html

I am trying to do a script when if you do not check a checkbox (in a form with post method) the php script sends you to the previous page (the one with the checkbox) and writes to check the checkbox this is the php script

PHP:

```
if(isset ($_POST["licencemessage"],$_POST["infomail"])){
    $userreg=$_POST["signuser"];
    $pwreg=$_POST["signpw"];
    $cpwreg=$_POST["confirmpw"];
    $minforeg=$_POST["infomail"];
    require_once("signin1.php");
}elseif(isset ($_POST["licencemessage"])){
    $userreg=$_POST["signuser"];
    $pwreg=$_POST["signpw"];
    $cpwreg=$_POST["confirmpw"];
    $minforeg=0;
    require_once("../signin1/signin1.php");
}else{
    header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
    echo "EXCEPT CONDITIONS";
}
```

Here is where I want to take the php script to take back to the previous page:

```
else{
    header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
    echo "EXCEPT CONDITIONS";
}
```

HTML checkbox

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="headbar">
        <img src="imgs/title.png" style="height:4em;float:left;"/> 

            <ul>        

                <li>    <a class="linkheaderbar"></a> </li>
                <li>    <a class="linkheaderbar"></a> </li>
                <li>    <a class="linkheaderbar"></a> </li>
            </ul>

    </div>          

    <div id="bodypage">
        <div id="formsign">
            <form action="php/logtest/signin/roba/var.php" method="post">
                <br>

                USERNAME<br><input type="text" name="signuser" class="font_form"class="floatright"value="insert username"/> 
                <br><br>
                PASSWORD<br><input  type="password" name="signpw" class="font_form"value=""/>
                <br><br>
                CONFIRM PASSWORD<br><input  type="password" name="confirmpw" class="font_form"value=""/>
                <br><br>
                MAIL<br><input  type="text" name="signmail" class="font_form"value=""/>
                <br><br>
                show my mail in info (read eula)<input  type="checkbox" name="infomail" class="font_form"value=""/>
                <br><br>
                i except the <a href="licence.html"class="randomlink">eula</a> conditions (please read it, there are only few rules) <input  type="checkbox" name="licencemessage" class="font_form"value=""/>
                <br><br>

                or just <a href="doc.html"class="randomlink">  log in</a><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="scrittefont" value="JOIN US"/>    
            </form>     
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

this is the checkbox:

```
i except the <a href="licence.html"class="randomlink">eula</a>   conditions (please read it, there are only few rules) <input  type="checkbox" name="licencemessage" class="font_form"value=""/>
            <br><br>
```

Comment: for one thing, you're outputting before header right now. and this isn't reliable `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: checkbox, what checkbox?

Comment: whops sorry i am adding the checkbox script

Comment: you can use sessions for this, while using a ternary operator http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php in the checkbox value.

Comment: for the checkbox i use the isset operatorin ithe if stantments i managed to go back but i cannot write things then

Comment: What is the current outcome you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Most people solve this problem by submitting the form to the current page. At the top of the page, before any HTML output is generated, a script is written to detect that the form has been submitted and validate it. If there is a validation problem, the a message is printed when the HTML is generated. If there is no validation problem then you can forward the submitted data to another script, or just process the data in the current script.

Alternatively, you could do it the way you have already tried, but when you redirect to the previous page, append the validation message as a GET parameter. E.g. 'header("Location: '\thepreviouspage.php?err=Validation%20Error'");'.